# Google structured data not showing in Google

Tags: e-commerce, search-engine, google-search

For an e-commerce website I've added review en pricing info to the product pages. I've tested it with Google structured data testing tool (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) and everything looks good. However, the strucutred  data (pricing and review) is not showing up in the google search results. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to use to votes property instead of count property for the reviews. Furthermore, structured data tool did show what the problem was. Funny thing is that I'm pretty sure it did not report any problems earlier when I made the code.